# Ряд Фибоначчи на Python

Tags: python

Нужно было написать код на Python опираясь на while, что бы он выводил Ряд Фибоначчи!
Я попробовал так:

```
fib1 = 0
fib2 = 0
while fib1 < 100 and fib2 < 100:
    fib1 += 1
    fib2 += 1
    i = fib1 + fib2 - 1
    print(i)
```

На мой взгляд всё правильно, но почему-то не работает:(

Прошу показать ошибку и исправить код.

Comment: Что значит не работает? Какая ошибка? Какой ожидаемый и реальный вывод?

Comment: По определению значения первых двух элементов ряда Фибоначчи - единицы (у вас почему-то нули). Следующие значения являются суммами двух предыдущих - у вас почему-то первоначальные значения в цикле увеличиваются на единицу. Ну и каждое новое значение должно становиться "предыдущим", по сути fib2 должно перемещаться в fib1, а новое (пусть будет i) - перемещаться в fib2.

Comment: Ожидаемый результат - вывод ряда Фибоначчи, в реале же выводит числа через  1, то есть 1 3 5 7 9 и тд до 199

Comment: Как же тут может быть все правильно на ваш взгляд, если в числах Фибоначчи по определению нигде нет увеличения на 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

один из нерекурсивных вариантов

```
fib1 = 0
fib2 = 1
fib3 = 1
print(fib1)
print(fib2)
print(fib3)

while fib3 < 100:
    fib1 = fib2
    fib2 = fib3
    fib3 = fib1 + fib2
    print(fib3)
```

Comment: Красивше было бы по-питоновски написать: `fib1, fib2, fib3 = fib2, fib3, fib1 + fib2`

Comment: @CrazyElf у меня почему то интерпретатор не хочет третье выражение присваивать в fib3 и оставляет старое значение, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Ай, я не прав. Последнее присваивание надо делать отдельно, оно должно делаться _после_ первого этого сдвига

Comment: `fib1, fib2 = fib2, fib3`, а потом отдельно `fib3 = fib1 + fib2` уже по новым значениям

Answer (score 3):

Вывод `N` элементов:

```
def fibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:            
        yield a            
        a, b = b, a + b 

for index, fibonacci_number in zip(range(42), fibonacci()):
     print('{} - {}'.format(index + 1, fibonacci_number))
```

Вывод элементов по условию:

```
def fibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:            
        yield a            
        a, b = b, a + b 

gen = fibonacci()
next_fibonacci_number = next(gen)

while next_fibonacci_number < 100:
  print(next_fibonacci_number)
  next_fibonacci_number = next(gen)
```

Answer (score 0):

Поробуйте так, но это выведет все числа до 100, а не 100 членов последовательности

```
fib1 = 0
fib2 = 1
while fib1 < 100 and fib2 < 100:
    i = fib1 + fib2
    fib1 = fib2
    fib2 = i
    print(i)
```